# How do I fully customise the default ASP .Net Core Identity pages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

I'm currently trying to learn and understand all the new Identity bits and pieces with .Net Core 2.1/MVC. Previously, I have used MVC3 MVC Identity and it was straight forward - it automatically created the Model, View and Controllers and I could easily edit everything and anything.

With .Net Core, it seems to automatically inherit everything from the framework and I just don't easily understand how to override.

I've followed the guides [located here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio), and have managed to scaffold all the pages (e.g. create user, reset password, login), however, this does not create any of the models or controllers.

Because of this, I now have a project with all the pages, but, it fails to build with all the models missing:

[image: [Output/Models missing]]

```
CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ChangePasswordModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

I feel like I am missing something obvious and I can't believe that I am struggling so much on something that ~10 years ago was simple.

How can I create/import the missing Controllers and models?

Comment: Post error message as text

Comment: Hi @barbsan - if you click the link, it will show all the error messages. I can't easily show a pic as I have less than 10 rep. The main problem is I can't see how to recreate the controller or models required to get identity to work :(

Comment: [is-it-ok-to-post-screenshots-with-error-messages-instead-of-copying-the-message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344250/is-it-ok-to-post-screenshots-with-error-messages-instead-of-copying-the-message)

Comment: @barbsan - Well, it doesn't really add anything... the fact is, there are no models as per the question text and title. All the picture shows is that they are missing... I'm going to try to edit this anyway.

Comment: Identity's default UI uses Razor Pages. There are no controllers, and the models are in the codebehind of the pages themselves. If you scaffolded them in, you should not be having any issues. You may simply need to rebuild your project.

Comment: Hi Chris, I followed the docs to the letter and can recreate this even on a blank project - when I create a new one and select identity, it builds/runs fine - if I then right click and scaffold all the document pages, the build fails and the error list (As above) shows that the models are missing - and, I can't rebuild due to the error. I don't suppose you can advise further please?

Comment: @ChrisPratt - I've just tried again and got the same error on a new project - then did it yet again, and it worked (well built fine)... I'm very sorry, something seems to be up with my VS/environment, I'm trying to quickly reinstall and I'll try again... I feel so silly now, but, thank you for your help... If these files basically contain everything that I used to see from identity back in the MVC3 days, please write the above as an answer as that is what I was looking for. ... It seems at random, my VS is not creating the code behind files, on the views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identity comes with a default UI composed of Razor Pages and static files housed in a Razor Class Library. It's added by default when you either use `AddDefaultIdentity` to enable Identity in your project or explicitly call `AddDefaultUI` on any of the other Identity bootstrapping extensions methods (`AddIdentity`/`AddIdentityCore`).

Views and static files in Razor Class Libraries are embedded resources, and as such are treated as if they physically existed directly in the apps that reference them. However, anything that actually does physically exist in your app will be used before any embedded resources. As such, you can override anything coming from an RCL, simply by creating the same file in the same location as it exists in the RCL in your app. The Identity scaffold simply copies over the selected Razor Pages into your project such that they will override in this way.

Since Razor Pages are used for the default UI, there's no controllers or separate model classes. The models used for the views are established in the Razor Page codebehinds, so for each page you scaffold in, you should have both `Page.cshtml` and `Page.cshtml.cs` files added.

If your build is failing after doing the scaffold, the build is not seeing the `*.cshtml.cs` files (codebehinds). Verify that they do exist in your project's file structure. If they don't, there's some fundamental problem with the scaffold in your instance of Visual Studio, which will likely require reinstalling or at least repairing Visual Studio.

Assuming they are there, then there's something stuck in the build process. Occasionally files do get locked and Visual Studio will complain that it's missing references, when in fact it's simply missing the very assemblies those come from. In such cases, you can navigate into your project directly and remove the `bin` and `obj` directories completely. Then, come back into Visual Studio and do a rebuild. If you have more than one project, you should rebuild your entire solution, as it could be a project reference that's actually failing to build.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like it was locking files/AV causing a few issues. I uninstalled the AV, did a reinstall of VS and everything is working as expected. I'll + you when I get enough rep to do so! :)